# How to read ID Token using MSAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I successfully acquire an ID Token along with an Access Token from Azure AD using MSAL.js in my Angular application.

The ID Token does contain information about the signed-in user. This would include roles and groups. However I do not understand how to read these values from the token stored in local storage. Does MSAL provide utilities to do so  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the more recent versions of the code it looks like there is a getAccount() function.

```
 this.authService.getAccount()
```

Comment: Indeed, thank you.  I had missed that. I could get what I want using `this.msalService.getAccount().idTokenClaims.roles`

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, if you want the raw ID Token, you can use

```
this.authService.getAccount().idToken
```

For example, this could give you the following string

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFMVE16YWtpaGlSbGFfOHoyQkVKVlhlV01xbyJ9.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.1AFWW-Ck5nROwSlltm7GzZvDwUkqvhSQpm55TQsmVo9Y59cLhRXpvB8n-55HCr9Z6G_31_UbeUkoz612I2j_Sm9FFShSDDjoaLQr54CreGIJvjtmS3EkK9a7SJBbcpL1MpUtlfygow39tFjY7EVNW9plWUvRrTgVk7lYLprvfzw-CIqw3gHC-T7IK_m_xkr08INERBtaecwhTeN4chPC4W3jdmw_lIxzC48YoQ0dB1L9-ImX98Egypfrlbm0IBL5spFzL6JDZIRRJOu8vecJvj1mq-IUhGt0MacxX8jdxYLP-KUu2d9MbNKpCKJuZ7p8gwTL5B7NlUdh_dmSviPWrw
```

This may be useful if you want to verify the signature.